# Escape string for Regex in Excel

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am trying to find keywords in an Excel cell.

```
Function findString(pattern As String, haystack As String)

    Dim RegEx As Object
    Dim strTest As String
    Dim valid As Boolean
    Dim Matches As Object

    Dim found As Boolean

    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    ' Initialise Regex object
    With RegEx
        '.Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
    End With

    ' I need something like this here:        
    'RegEx.pattern = RegEx.Escape(pattern)
    RegEx.pattern = pattern

    'return value
    findString = RegEx.test(haystack)

    Set RegEx = Nothing

End Function
```

pattern is the keyword.
However, this keyword can contain special characters. Example: D|Sign
This should be escaped to "D\|Sign" before regex is executed.

How can I escape this string so that only cells containing the input string are found?

Comment: How would you know whether a special character in the pattern needs to be escaped or not? Did whoever wrote the pattern mean to use `|` as `or`, or are they looking for a literal `|` ?  It should be up to the writer of `pattern` to do the required escaping...

Answer (score 1):

With no obvious escape function I would suggest you write one...

Escape all characters into their Unicode value.

Iterate though each input character and get the Unicode character value via [AscW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zew1e4wc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and prefix it with `\u`.

So the string `Aa` would look like this `\u0065\u0097`